# onmouseover acts like an onclick, not a hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onmouseover, onmouseout

I have a table of "cards", and I want to display a description on top of the card each time the mouse is passed over the card. To do that, I'm trying to use onmouseover and onmouseout functions.

**My Javascript:**

```
function showDescription(obj) {
  elem1 = document.getElementById(obj + '_1');
  elem1.style.display = 'none';

  elem2 = document.getElementById(obj + '_2');
  elem2.style.display = 'block';
}

function hideDescription(obj) {
  elem1 = document.getElementById(obj + '_1');
  elem1.style.display = 'block';

  elem2 = document.getElementById(obj + '_2');
  elem2.style.display = 'none';
}
```

**My HTML:**

```
<table id='teamTable' align="center">
  <tr>
    <td onmouseover="showDescription('content_1')" onmouseout="hideDescription('content_1')">
      <div id="content_1_1" class="teamTableTitle">
        Name
      </div>
      <div id="content_1_2" class="teamTableDescription">
        Description
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/rys8r4q9/)

The problem is that my two events onmouseover and onmouseout act like if they where onclick. Nothing happens the mouse is passed over the card, but it works when I click...

Anyone knows what I did wrong ?  :/

Comment: make a fiddle please.

Comment: "display a description on top of the card ". Do you mean something like title?

Comment: Please use addEventListeners. BTW couldn't understand ur question in detail

Comment: It works fine for me. Which browser you are testing in?

Comment: The question is that when I have this : <div onmouseover="alert('Hello')">This is a test.</div>, I have to click to display the alert. It does not appear when the mouse is passed over.

Comment: I use Safari. But you're right, i've just checked and it works on Firefox...

Comment: Check this : https://jsfiddle.net/4mbjx7q4/

Comment: Try to use proper tag like <head>script goes here</head><body>html</body>. Browsers discriminate.

Answer (score 0):

Base on my understanding on your code. I came up with this and converted it into jQuery

HTML

```
<table id='teamTable' align="center">
     <tr>
        <td id="content_1">
            <div id="content_1_1" class="teamTableTitle">
                 Name (Hover me to show description)
            </div>
            <div id="content_1_2" class="teamTableDescription">
                 Description
            </div>
        </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

JS (jQuery)

```
$('#content_1').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('div').eq(0).hide().next('div').show();
},function(){
    $(this).find('div').eq(0).show().next('div').hide();
});
```

[**Click this for working JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/3ry18g31/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jQueryless solution to your problem :

**HTML**

```
<table id='teamTable' align="center">
  <tr>
    <td class="td-test">
      <div id="content_1_1" class="teamTableTitle">
        Name
      </div>
      <div id="content_1_2" class="teamTableDescription">
        Description
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
var tableEl = document.getElementsByClassName('td-test');

tableEl[0].addEventListener("mouseover", showDescription, false);
tableEl[0].addEventListener("mouseout", hideDescription, false);

function showDescription() {
  var el1 = this.querySelector("#content_1_1");
  var el2 = this.querySelector("#content_1_2");

  el1.style.display = "none";
  el2.style.display = "block";
}

function hideDescription() {
  var el1 = this.querySelector("#content_1_1");
  var el2 = this.querySelector("#content_1_2");

  el1.style.display = 'block';
  el2.style.display = 'none';
}
```